# Excel Last Date based on account number

Tags: excel

I currently have a formula which is supposed to identify the Last Payment Date per account number, where several payments are shown per account number. The LastPmtDate and Docdate is the same.

```
{MAX(COLUMN($D1:$D10000)*($D$1:$D$10000=D2))}
```

The data looks as follows, starting from A1 in the spreadsheet.

```
AccountCode Amt Amt2 DocDate DocType LastPmtDate
1            10                      2017/05/02
1            12                      2017/06/01
```

The formula should pick up the 2017/06/01 date in the column to the right of the LastPmtDate so I can quickly pick it up.

Comment: Isn't your last payment date column F using this sample data?  Why is your formula looking at column D?

Comment: Column D and F is the same.

Comment: ok, we'll assume Column D is populated with identical data to column F.  How does the formula know which account number you're interested in?  This list of account numbers are in column A, correct?  Are you hardcoding which account number to look for or is there a cell reference?

Comment: Column A contains the acctcode, yes. I will make use of a cell reference for the accountcode. It doesnt know, which is where I'm struggling.

Comment: `COLUMN($D1:$D10000)` is going to be `4` no matter what anything else is.

Comment: You are correct Jeeped. The formula is an array though, which is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a reference cell of H1 (which contains the account number you're looking for), use this formula and format it as date:

```
=MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$10000=H1)*$F$2:$F$10000,))
```